# Loop several data frames using R

Tags: r, loops

I want to filter a group of data frames, first by a p.value and then divide it in two by the value of the t.

This is how I do it for just one data frame.

```
p.value.cut <- which(top_Na1$P.Value < 0.05)
top_Na1 <- top_Na1[p.value.cut,]    

up <- which(top_Na1$t > 0)
down <- which(top_Na1$t < 0)

up.p.value <- top_Na1[up,]
down.p.value <- top_Na1[down,]
```

Whenever I try to replicate this using a loop for or `apply`, `sapply`, `lapply` I end applying changes to all columns or not being able to work with a proper column (it looks like the for loop doesn't uses the whole data frame but it goes column by column) or I just lose the row names of the data frame (like with some `apply`).

This is how one of the data frames looks like (all are the same).

```
               logFC         t     P.Value  adj.P.Val         B
YMR290C   -0.1952028 -4.593506 0.003484478 0.03596870 -1.602151
YBR090C   -0.3406244 -4.373073 0.004429437 0.03930581 -1.857238
YPL037C   -0.8737048 -4.088782 0.006100105 0.04526780 -2.197584
YGL035C   -0.3058778 -3.839335 0.008159371 0.05142077 -2.506721
```

Comment: You didn't show the code you've tried to apply this across all your data frames. Usually a good way to apply the same code across a set of data frames is to store them in a list, e.g. `l <- list(df1, df2, df3)`, and then apply your processing function to the list with `lapply(l, process)`.

Comment: @biorunner88 I would also suggest to read all the data.frames into a list rather than creating individual data.frame objects. ie. `files <- list.files(); lst <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE)`. Then try as josiber suggested

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. It's solved. The problem was on the way I was creating the list.

This way worked.

```
l <- list(top_Na1, top_Na2)

function_filtering <- function(x){
  p.value.cut <- which(x$P.Value < 0.05)
  x <- x[p.value.cut,]    

  up <- which(x$t > 0)
  down <- which(x$t < 0)

  up.p.value <- x[up,]
  down.p.value <- x[down,]

  }

  lapply(l, function_filtering)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that "/tmp/dat.txt" contains your sample data.frame. The code below should do what you want.

```
d <- read.table("/tmp/dat.txt")
d[1,"P.Value"] <- 0.05 # to make the example more general
d[2,"t"] <- -d[2,"t"] # to make the example more general
input <- list(d,d) # generating a list of data frames for testing purposes

cutIt <- function(x) {
  y <- x[x$P.Value < 0.05,]
  list(up=y[y$t > 0,],down=y[y$t <= 0,])
}

lapply(input,cutIt)
```